# How do thresholded incentives influence behavior?

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-economics, utility, simulations

I'm trying to understand how incentives can change crowds in terms of their work performance. I have metrics describing said performance and I'm trying to see how introducing incentives might change those metrics. I want to introduce a tiered reward program and I'm trying to understand the effect of that.

In particular, I’d like to understand how their current metric performance might influence their likelihood to move, depending on reward desirability and tier threshold. For example, if a person has a metric of 10 and the target is 100, they might be less likely to change, relative to someone who is already at 90.

Are there any terms or research that describe this type of problem?